# Playing specific system sound with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, audio, qt5

I want my application to emit a standard notification sound, the one that's called "Default Beep" on Windows. I don't see a way of referencing system sounds with QSound. QSound instance with no sound assigned used to play this sound, but it's fixed in Qt 5. Any way to do it?

It's OK if the solution only works on Windows (but I want it to compile on any supported OS and don't want to use `#ifdef` and Win API).

Answer (score 1):

Use Phonon ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html ), a Qt library, which is able to play sound / video, ...

For the path of the file, you should use environment variable for the WINDOWS directory, and then hard code the end of the path of the sound file

**But :** I am thinking that it may **not** a good idea, since the system sound can be personalized... To get the PATH of the personalized sound you need to read the windows registry...

**Edit :** You could use the `QSettings` class to be able to read the Windows registry 
For example something like :

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\AppEvents\\Schemes\Apps\\.Defaults\\..TODO..", QSettings::NativeFormat);
```

Comment: Try reading twice, a little help : read the section : "Playback", There is even an example

Comment: Why not hard coding the path of the sound file ? See the edited answer

Comment: Now your answer is complete, but I wonder if there's a better way, a cross-platform one. Your solution can't even account for the current sound theme.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide the idea for the implementation... **But** this is not going to be easy/fast to implement