# Play standard notification / system sounds

Tags: c++, qt, audio

On windows I can play system sounds like shown in [How to play a standard windows sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72167/356726) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72250/356726) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712868(VS.85).aspx) .

Is there a unified Qt way to do the same on different platforms, or a library to do so.

[Playing specific system sound with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14110563/356726) shows how to play a sound with Qt, but there is no standardized way and I would need to do play file names directly (ie loosing using user settings).

I would like to call something like `play(Warning)` and hear the appropriate sound on the different OS.

Comment: I strongly doubt this is possible, since each OS is a little different when it comes to which sounds are available.